# MySQL 8.0.23.0 change Type and Networking

Tags: mysql, windows-10

My problem is that MySQL Command Line Client and other services do not start. Not even after the developer default installation.

Looking at the different error messages, it seems the cause of skipping the type and network window. During installation there should be the option to set the type and network. However, that window and the following windows weren't shown during installation.

My question is what I did wrong during installation and how to solve the problem. Re-install didn't help actually. Nor did restart.

The installation is performed on a brand new Windows 10 laptop

Below some printscreens of the situation and error messages:

- [The error message I got when trying to open MySQL via the command prompt as administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxuoh.png)
- [The Type and Network window which did not show up during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grxIO.png)
- [Service was added and activated after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyO41.png)
- [Opening the Local Instance MySQL under "MySQL Connections" gave this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uHRc.png)
- [The Workbench error showed after pressing "OK" in this window without a password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q11mm.png)
- [The tile under "MySQL Connections" did I try to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEl3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just not entering your password. I'm not really spotting anything else.

Comment: The problem is I never set a password. That is because the Type and Network window never showed during installation

Comment: Solved the problem. Apparently, there is the option to reconfigure after installing by re-opening the MySQL Installer and clicking reconfigure for the Server. Killing the tasks on the 3306 port made it possible to follow the Type and Networking steps without a problem.Tom, thanks for looking at my post and the help